# RAML default envelope

Tags: api, api-design, raml

My API has a default envelope for all collection-type resources, like the following:

```
{
  "data": [{},{},{}],
  "self": "http://api-url/members",
  "total": 120,
  "limit": 10,
  "offset": 0
}
```

Is it possible to define this using RAML? Inside a resourceType? How?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are using for specifying your API's entities:

- `JSON Schema Draft 3` - Create a base schema with these common fields and use the `extends` mechanism in each concrete schema,
- `JSON Schema Draft 4` - Create a shared schema with these common fields and use the `allOf` mechanism to mix it in each concrete schema,
- `RAML 1.0 Types` - Create a common type and refer to it in each concrete type via the `type` attribute.

Comment: Seems like there is a typo perhaps the 2nd bullet here refers to Draft 4?

Answer (score 1):

With RAML 1 you can use types and inheritance to define your envelope and data types. And resource types for applying to all collection-type resources, for example:

```
types:
    person:
        type: object
        properties:
            name:
            age:
    car:
        type: object
        properties:
           model:
           brand:
    envelop:
        type: object
        properties:
            data: person[] | car[]
            self: string
            total: integer
            limit: integer
            offset: integer
resourceTypes:
    - collection:
        get:
            responses:
                200:
                    body:
                        type: envelope
/users:
    type: collection
    get:
```

More info [here](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#raml-data-types), [here](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#multiple-inheritance) and [here](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#resource-types-and-traits)

Comment: the reference links are broken